# Get properties value from parent user control

Tags: c#, asp.net, reflection, .net-2.0

I want to create a method to get a value from the parent user control but `PropertyInfo` can't get the value from the parent control and throws an exception. I think this is happening because it's not the object's actual type.

I am using .NET 2 so I can't use dynamic keyword.

Is there any way to do this?

```
    public object GetFromPar(Control parent, string propertyName, Type parentType)
    {
        while (parent != null)
        {
            if (parent.GetType().IsSubclassOf(parentType))
            {
                PropertyInfo info = parent.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName);
                return info.GetValue(parent, null);
            }
            else
            {
                parent = parent.Parent;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
```

And this is how i call this function.

```
this.GetFromPar(this.Parent, "Name", typeof(InfoControl));
```

InfoControl is a user control that was a parent of LoginPanelControl (this).

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Which exceptions you have exactly.

Comment: Exception: TargetInvocationException                
InnerException: Specified cast is not valid.

Comment: @LastFrog What line is the exception occurring on?

Comment: It's happend from info.GetValue(parent, null);

Comment: Can you show how you are calling this method?  I just tried it with a basic `Form` using the following syntax and it worked just fine:  `GetFromPar(this, "Name", typeof(Form));`

Answer (score 0):

```
PropertyInfo info = (typeof(parent.GetType())).GetProperty(propertyName);
```

If you know the type of the parent, you can substitute that for parent.GetType().

Comment: Parent doesn't have GetProperty().

Comment: That's not a problem.
What's you mean is that I can do this     "parent.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName);" Right?

Comment: But i can't get value by "info.GetValue(parent, null);"
I think because the type was different and it's may see parent as Control not an InfoPanel.

Comment: What I mean is you can try: PropertyInfo info = (typeof(ParentType)).GetProperty(propertyName);